# with OutputCache random user have to pay cost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outputcache

I'm using OutputCache to avoid execute same code everytime, but I have the following problem:

when it expires, a random user have to pay the cost to execute this code.  Can avoid it??

I'm using asp.net MVC 4.0.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data is really immutable, you can set Duration property to max value and forget.

But if cache entry expires, you have to load fresh data anyway. By design, OutputCacheAttribute allows to load data on demand only. If you want to precache data, you should invent your own caching mechanism, or extend OutputCacheAttribute someway.